# Defragmentation of SQL Server 2008 indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, fragmentation

I am having issues defragmenting indexes. I keep using the various defragmentation methods for defragmenting a SQL Server index such as `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG` and `DBCC DBReIndex`, but none seem to be changing the fragmentation.

I have even tried the method suggested here in this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177571.aspx
but with no change.

Comment: Explain how you know that it is not "*changing fragmentation*".  Be specific.

Comment: How many pages in your tables? What issue do you think defragmentation is going to fix in your case, except that it is reducing the number that you see under frag %?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28182.sql-server-in-depth-what-can-cause-index-to-be-still-fragmented-after-rebuild.aspx probably you are rebuilding index with page count < 1000 have a look at the article